# how can I enable auto tags and remove scapes from other on my wordpress editor?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the wordpress editor with my own template, so, its the most basic one.

My problem is when I go to the `text` mode, and for example i inserte `<p>Something</p>` and later go back to visual, its there... but If i go back to the `text` format, there are no `<p>` anymore.

The same way if I use the visual mode and I choose paragraph and later I start writting, I go to text mode and there is only text, no tagging at all.

How can I add this tags and avoid scaping them if I insert them on the text mode?

Thanks.

Comment: Wordpress by default actually [inserts <p> tags into posts with line breaks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) It might be that you're just seeing Wordpress 'strip away' tags that will already be there when you hit publish.

Comment: I checked on the output html, and yes, it has the p tag, but , is there any way to see the tag in the editor on text mode?

Comment: For some reason is my template the one who scapes the <p> tag, any idea?